# MYSQL returns empty result in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following tableCountry

```
country  clicks
-------  ------
0        222
66       34 
175      1000
45       650
```

And I use the following MYSQL statement to get the ranking of any of the country based on the clicks column (just one result)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) rank 
FROM countryTable a 
JOIN countryTable b 
   ON a.clicks <= b.clicks 
WHERE a.country = 45
```

The above will return '2'. Then in my php code I try to access the rank value with

```
$row =  mysql_fetch_array($result) or die(mysql_error()); 
echo $row['rank'];
```

But this doesn't return any result if the country is the number one. i.e a.country = 175

Comment: Have you tried `mysql_fetch_assoc`? Also please use mysqli or PDO extensions.

Comment: @user1190992 I have and it doesn't return any result also. How do I use mysqli?

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with fetch_assoc or mysqli or pdo. It's the SQL itself.

Comment: @ThanhTrung the Answer you gave below does not work unfortunately

Comment: @PutraKg how is a rank calculated?

Comment: @ThanhTrung it's based on the clicks.

Comment: @PutraKg I know, but in term of phrase, are you searching for all country that has clicks smaller than a given country?

Comment: I would think so. But those countries with the same number of clicks should have similar ranking. BTW, the mysql statement works as I have tested it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fe22/2 . It just the PHP script that does not return any value when it's the number one country

Answer (score 1):

A join ON is a join between columns, not a comparison.

**UPDATED**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)+1 rank 
FROM countryTable
WHERE clicks > (SELECT clicks FROM countryTable WHERE country = 45)
```

Reasoning: searching for a rank mean searching for the number of records that has clicks > a given click.

Therefore, for 175 there is 0 country with better click => rank 1, country 45, 1 country with better click => rank 2

**PHP**

```
$result = mysql_query("....")
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
...
```

Normally it should work unless you got a problem with connecting to the server. That's where you should use your debugging skill. Do a var_dump($result) to see if it return false, if yes then it's a connection problem (check mysql_connect or something)

Comment: Thanks. Just tried this but it didn't return the correct ranking. Getting the first ranking still returns the blank result also

Comment: Error: Unknown column 'a.country' in 'where clause'. BTW I have tried several mysql statement which are all correctly returning values in MYSQL. But in PHP all returns nothing for the number one country.

Comment: It's fixed, try this new sql

Comment: The new sql is correct. But how do I get $row['rank'] = 1 for the the number one country? I still get a blank result in php (not mysql).

Comment: That's what I am using and strangely it doesn't return any value only when the country is number one in the ranking. It's not a connection problem for sure because the problem is specific to that condition. I am not a PHP or MYSQL programmer so I can't go far with my own debugging :(

Comment: I tested var_dump($result) but it doesn't return any value when it's the number one ranking country. How can this be a connection problem when other queries is returning the correct result?

Comment: Then again my friend, I have no idea. $result should always contain a resource of "false". If it doesn't show up any anything, it means that your code is broken somewhere, maybe above it. Like mysql_query is not executing

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for ranking, use this:

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS num,
    t.country, t.clicks
FROM countryTable t, 
    (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
ORDER BY t.clicks DESC
```

**Result**

```
| NUM | COUNTRY | CLICKS |
--------------------------
|   1 |     175 |   1000 |
|   2 |      45 |    650 |
|   3 |       0 |    222 |
|   4 |      66 |     34 |
```

### [See it in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/30601/2)

Comment: Thanks. In my case though I just want the query to return one result. The problem I have is accessing the return value in PHP when the country ranked 1.

Comment: Interesting, this way you can have a list of rank when you need it. You can simply get a record with WHERE country=id_country

Answer (score 0):

@PutraKg I think you can close this question, because I answered it in this post [MYSQL does not return result in PHP when asked for the first ranking only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14300868/mysql-does-not-return-result-in-php-when-asked-for-the-first-ranking-only/14303343#14303343) ;-)