# MYSQL does not return result in PHP when asked for the first ranking only

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get hold of 1 record from a MySQL table using PHP. I have tried many different SELECT statements, while they all work in MYSQL they refuse to return any result in php.

The countriesRanking table is a simple two column table

```
country    clicks
------     ------
0        222
66       34 
175      1000
45       650
```

The mysql returns the ranking of the country column (1, 2, 3, etc..) and it returned all results EXCEPT the first ranked country. Eg when country=175, should return 1 but no result returned. Direct query via web browser return blank page, no error message. My PHP code

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT FIND_IN_SET(clicks,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT clicks  ORDER BY clicks DESC) 
FROM countriesRanking)) rank FROM countriesRanking
WHERE country = '$country'") or die(mysql_error());

$row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die(mysql_error());
$theranking = $row['rank'];
echo $theranking;
```

EDIT

I tried the following but get the same blank page

```
var_dump($row['rank']);
```

EDIT 2

For a successful query print_r($result) returned something like Resource id #4. While print_r($row) returned Array ( [0] => 4 [rank] => 4 ). But when querying for the top ranking country. eg country=175, it returned a blank page.

Comment: This exact question was closed, why do you reopen it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295509/mysql-returns-empty-result-in-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294542/find-the-ranking-of-an-integer-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. It is based on your earlier question. [MYSQL returns empty result in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295509/mysql-returns-empty-result-in-php)
 MYSQLI version:

```
<?PHP
function rank(){
/* connect to database */
$hostname = 'server';
$user = 'username';
$password = 'password';
$database = 'database';

    $link = mysqli_connect($hostname,$user,$password,$database);

    /* check connection */

    if (!$link){ 
        echo ('Unable to connect to the database');
    }

    else{
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) rank FROM countryTable a JOIN countryTable b ON a.clicks <= b.clicks WHERE a.country = 175";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    $arr_result =  mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_BOTH); 
        return $arr_result['rank'];
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
}

echo rank();

?>
```

MYSQL version:

```
<?PHP
function rank(){
  /* connect to database */
  $hostname = 'server';
  $user = 'username';
  $password = 'password';
  $database = 'database';

  $link = mysql_connect($hostname,$user,$password);

  /* check connection */

  if (!$link){ 
    echo ('Unable to connect to the database');
  }

  else{
  $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) rank FROM countryTable a JOIN countryTable b ON a.clicks <= b.clicks WHERE a.country = 66";
  mysql_select_db($database);
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  $arr_result = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_BOTH); 
  return $arr_result['rank'];
  }
  mysql_close($link);
}

echo rank();

?>
```

Comment: I get 'Array' for the top ranked country

Comment: If you change "return $arr_result" into "return $arr_result['rank'] " it should give you the correct result.

Comment: Finally! Yes it gives the correct result. But it made me wonder why it doesn't work with mysql. I am not a php programmer so converting my script to mysqli will require me to start from the beginning.

Comment: Hi, it does work with mysql. However, as soon as you upgrade to version 5.5. from PHP mysql will not work. I will recode it into mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are not getting an error that means you are successfully connecting to your database. You are just not getting back any values.
Try:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

I would usually think $row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result); would work but if neither of these work it must be something within your mysql_query.

Comment: I've just tried $row = mysql_fetch_row($result); But it didn't work also. It returned blank page for other queries as well. I tried many other SELECT statements but they all refused to return the number 1 ranking.

Comment: @PutraKg: Alright, then are you sure your SELECT query is correct? Try a simpler example first to see if you can get a value that way... meaning the query was the issue not the other code.      $result = mysql_query("SELECT rank FROM countriesRanking WHERE country = '$country'") or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Yes the SELECT query was tested in phpmyadmin and it returned the correct value. As for your suggestion, 'rank' is not one of the columns. The rank has to be 'calculated' via the query.

Comment: @PutraKg: Alright if you tried dumping the $result and $row variables to see what those are set as? I would try and output those to see what those look like and find where any potential hold up could be.

Comment: For a successful query print_r($result) returned something like Resource id #4. While print_r($row) returned Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [rank] => 4
).

But when querying for the top ranking country. eg country=175, it returned a blank page

Comment: @PutraKg: Interesting well in that case if print_r($row) returned that array then $row[rank] should equal 4. Maybe rank is being stored as a variable not a string. If I am not reading your comment incorrectly try $theranking = $row[rank]; without the single quotes.

Comment: I get  "Use of undefined constant rank" when removing the single quotes

Comment: @PutraKg: Wow that is confusing... if print_r($row) returned that array you left in the comments than your code should work... Are you even able to return $row[0] because that was set as 4 also?

Comment: Yes this is confusing.. It returned the correct value using $row[0]

Comment: @PutraKg: Well I know it is a little unconventional but since you are returning only one value and those two values will always be the same I guess you could just use that. Even though it is weird how 'rank' is not working.

Comment: That's right. But the main problem I am having is not getting the return value, it's getting the return value when the rank is number one. It returns a blank page for both $row[0] and $row['rank']

Answer (score 1):

You can debug this as below.

1. make sure your SQL is correct by running it on PHPMyAdmin and check the result.
2. make sure you don't have any fatal errors, if you get a blank page there is something wrong. Turn on PHP errors and see.
3. `print_r($result)` and see whether it's empty.
4. if you want first ranking only then add the LIMIT 1 to your query

Comment: 1. Yes the SQL was tested on PHPMYAdmin and the produce the correct result.<br/>
2. Added ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL); but no message when I get the blank page.<br/>
3. print_r($result) returned a blank page<br/>
4. Done that<br/>

Answer (score 1):

If you want only one record from database than you have to use limit in query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT FIND_IN_SET(clicks,
(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT clicks  ORDER BY clicks DESC) 
FROM countriesRanking)) rank FROM countriesRanking
WHERE country = '$country' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

and after that use `while` loop

```
while($row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $theranking = $row['rank'];
}
echo $theranking;
```

Comment: Thanks. Just tried that but it's still returning blank page for the number one ranking

Comment: @PutraKg have you tried this same query in phpmyadmin? may be it doesn't return any result.

Comment: Yes I always try the query in phpmyadmin first to make sure. It returned the correct result there but it did not return the value when assigning the result in php variable.

Comment: @PutraKg Ok. If it is returning result in phpmyadmin then try this code `print_r($row)` and show its result in your question.

Comment: OK print_r($row) return Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [rank] => 2
)

for other query but return blank page when asked for the first ranking.

Comment: OK, tried that. It still returning blank when querying for the top ranked country but return proper results for other queries.